# How to grep and append archives separate than folders

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to identify a string(pattern) provided as an argument on command-line.I need to search only in just current directory and archives and also to append it to two different folders(.txt) one with the folders and one with archives.

My command is  `grep -s -R -E $1 >> text.txt` and i m using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS.
Is there a different command to search my string through all types of archives or maybe just tar and zip(if it`s possible)? 
My objective is to have one folder with all the files from current directory that contains my string(pattern) and one folder with all the archives from current directory that contains my string(pattern).I think that my command already do this thing but only for folders froom current directory..Any ideas how to do it for archives?

Edit: tried this code,it`s working but as you can see in my screenshot the output of text.txt contains ALL archives not just the one with the string.Tried with another string and still output ALL gzip and zip archives even if doesn t contain the string "$1".For example in the screenshot provided the output should be only first.zip because it contains the string "sample"

```
for f in *.zip
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    found=$(zgrep -q "$1" "$f")
    if [ ! $found ]; then
      echo "$f" >> text.txt
    fi
  fi
done
```

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a pattern for all archives in a directory(You can add more types if you want):

```
for f in *.tar.gz 
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    tar -xvzf "$f" -O | grep -sE "Pattern" >> text.txt
  fi
done

for f in *.zip
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    zgrep "pattern" "$f" >> test.txt
  fi
done
```

Basically it works like this :

- For loops look for archives in the current directory.
- Before extracting we check if there is any file to be extracted.
- `tar -xvfz` with `-O` flag extracts  `$f` which is a `.tar.gz` file to standard output and the output is given to grep by pipe.
- `zgrep` is similar to grep, but it works for zip and `gzip` files. Unlike grep, It doesn't support `-R` flag(Recursive).

**Edit**: 
If you only want grep/zgrep return true or false, not the matched text:

```
for f in *.tar.gz 
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    found=$(tar -xvzf "$f" -O | grep -sE "Enabled")
    if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
      echo "$f" >> text.txt
    fi
  fi

done

for f in *.zip
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    found=$(zgrep  "pattern" "$f")
    if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
      echo "$f" >> text.txt
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer!! I will try ths code in a few hours and i will come back with an answer!!Ty

Comment: I have an error: tar:Options ' -[0-7][lmh]' not supported by *this* tar

Comment: @NistorMihnea How did you use the code?

Comment: @arianman5 take a look on my screenshot  that i edited on my post

Comment: The code works fine. This is a problem with tar that is discussed here  https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28706232/tar-Options-'-0-7-lmh-'-not-supported-by-this-tar.html#succeeded

Comment: i have an error on the second 'for' with zip files. Gzip: string.gz No such file or directory(i think my input should be an already created file/directory but that is no what i need, i need to find all archives that contain my string)

Comment: @NistorMihnea perhaps there is space in your file name? Changed the code for that.

Comment: No the code is wrote correctly..i post 2 ss on my post so you can see what i`m talking about

Comment: @NistorMihnea Yeah i wrote zgrep  arguments in the wrong order. Check my code again.

Comment: Right now it`s working but i have one more issue:the thing is after i do cat text.txt it should output the name of archive not the name of the string,i posted a screenshot on edit so you cann see what i mean.As you can see i created a zip called "me.zip" and i archived two folders (f4 and f5 ) which both contains "alex".So in my text.txt should be "me.zip" or just "me" not the string "alex" i mean it should contain the name of archive which contain the string not the string itself. I edited My post with a screenshot.Thanks in advance

Comment: @NistorMihnea That was never explained in the original post! You can check if the output of zgrep and grep is empty, if it's not, echo "$f" >> file.txt.

Comment: how i can check if this output of zgrep and grep is empty? cat me.zip?

Comment: @NistorMihnea  lets say you assigned the output to a variable d. You can check if d is empty  with if [ -z "$d"]; then...

Comment: ok so i have ' for f in *.zip do if [         ]; then echo "$f" >> file2.txt fi done'. So what should i put in if  behind [ ]to search for my "$1" pattern in those zip files?

Comment: @NistorMihnea Added code for that scenario.

Comment: Made an edit to the original post because i have one problem with that,it outputs all archives even if contains or not the string provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107945/discussion-between-ariaman5-and-nistor-mihnea).